# Getting sonar-runner to work with C code

Tags: c, sonarqube

I am trying to use [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). The server is up and running (using the default embedded derby database), serving a web page with no projects. Then I was planning to use sonar-runner to examine the source code, but I cannot get it to work even with the simplest hello world program. Any hints on what is missing/I am doing wrong?

```
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar>wget -q http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-runner/1.1/sonar-runner-1.1.zip
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar>unzip sonar-runner-1.1.zip
Archive:  sonar-runner-1.1.zip
   creating: sonar-runner-1.1/
...
  inflating: sonar-runner-1.1/lib/sonar-runner.jar  
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar>export SONAR_RUNNER_HOME=/work/sonar/sonar-runner-1.1
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar>$SONAR_RUNNER_HOME/bin/sonar-runner -h

usage: sonar-runner [options]

Options:
 -h,--help             Display help information
 -X,--debug            Produce execution debug output
 -D,--define <arg>     Define property
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar>
```

But trying to run sonar-runner fails:

```
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar>cd helloworld/
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar/helloworld>cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("hello world\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar/helloworld>grep -v -E '^#|^$' sonar-runner.properties 
sonar.projectKey=helloworld
sonar.projectName=Hello world
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=c
sources=/work/sonar/helloworld
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar/helloworld>$SONAR_RUNNER_HOME/bin/sonar-runner 
Runner settings: /work/sonar/sonar-runner-1.1/conf/sonar-runner.properties
Runner version: 1.1
Server: http://localhost:9000
Work directory: /work/sonar/helloworld/.sonar
[INFO]  Database dialect class org.sonar.jpa.dialect.Derby
[INFO]  Initializing Hibernate
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex@3d57211f, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:155)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:58)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:52)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex@3d57211f, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
        at org.picocontainer.monitors.NullComponentMonitor.lifecycleInvocationFailed(NullComponentMonitor.java:77)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:115)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:996)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:989)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:746)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:88)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:96)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:60)
        at org.sonar.runner.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:152)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:130)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonar.api.resources.Resource.hashCode(Resource.java:242)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:389)
        at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.doStart(DefaultIndex.java:98)
        at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.start(DefaultIndex.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        ... 21 more
(hlovdal) localhost:/work/sonar/helloworld>
```

Answer (score 1):

The projectKey does not look correct, it should be something like xxx:yyy

Comment: Excellent, that sounds reasonable. I am currently working at a different project and at a different office, so I'll wait with accepting until I have verified. Thanks for your answer.